# MotoMaster Eliminator 1400A Booster

Tags: battery, charging, replace, service, charger

I have one question about charger booster. I have MotoMaster Eliminator 1400A Booster bought in 2014. I think its battery is dead, because it does not boost the car even when it is fully charged. Can you advice is it possible to fix it and how much will it cost or it is time to buy new one.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Test the battery and replace as necessary. Or replace the device.

Comment: I don't think these devices are meant to be serviceable. My guess would be replacement may be your only option.